# warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|

Tags: c, char

```
/* Beginning 2.0 */
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf(" %d signifies the %c of %f",9,'rise',17.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Hello people

When I compile this, the compiler giving the following warning:

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]|
```

And the output only prints `e` instead of `rise`.

Are multiple characters not allowed in C?

How can I print the whole word (`rise`)?

Please help me out.

Comment: Tangent: say `int main()`, not `main()`, the latter is obsolete abd considered sloppy.

Answer (score 11):

Use `%s` and `""` for a character string:

```
printf(" %d signifies the %s of %f",9,"rise",17.0);
                          ^^          ^    ^
```

For `'rise'`, this is valid **ISO 9899:1999 C**. It compiles without warning under gcc with `-Wall`, and a `“multi-character character constant”` warning with `-pedantic`.

According to the standard (**§6.4.4.4.10**),

- `The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), [...] is implementation-defined.`

Answer (score 10):

Try: `printf(" %d signifies the %s of %f",9,"rise",17.0);`.

C distinguishes between a character (which is *one* character) and a character *string* (which can contain an arbitrary number of characters). You use single quotes (`''`) to signify a character literal, but double quotes to signify a character *string* literal.

Likewise, you specify `%c` to convert a single character, but `%s` to convert a string.