# char containing single character when assigning `ab`

Tags: c, char

When I declare `char ch = 'ab'` , `ch` contains only 'b', why it is not storing 'a'?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char ch = 'ab';
  printf("%c",ch);
  return 0;
}
```

What is the actual process involved here?

Comment: `char ch = 'ab';` should give a warnings such as `warning: multi-character character constant` and `warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' `. Don't do it, it's implementation specific stuff you don't need as a beginner.

Comment: @SrujanLanderi what compiler / IDE are you using?

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled (`-Wall` with gcc and clang, but it might be different in your environnment).

Comment: [C11 6.4.4.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) p10: "The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab') [...] is implementation-defined." Apparently, in your implementation `'ab'` maps to `'b'`.

Comment: @pmg The fact he gets 'b' is mostly due to to the truncation of a >8 bit value to a char.

Comment: @andrei985 I use Code Blocks

Comment: @Jabberwocky: that's my guess about his implementation too. I believe `if ('ab' == ('a' * 256 + 'b')) puts("I'm right");` prints "I'm right" on his computer :)  ---  https://ideone.com/Vfxsun

Comment: @SrujanLanderi for setting compiler flags in codeblocks read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208733/how-to-add-compiler-flags-on-codeblocks). You absolutely need to use `-Wall` and consider most if not all warnings as errors.

Comment: @SrujanLanderi Try enabling the warnings as shown [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/configuring-your-compiler-warning-and-error-levels/) or how other people suggested in the comments

Comment: @andrei985 forget my comment, I deleted it, you can delete your last comment too, and I'll delete this comment in a few minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the single quote marks `'` to contain the `ab` string, you have created what is known as a multi-character constant. The behaviour of your program is implementation-defined, meaning that if I have a different compiler or OS, I might see the value `a`, even though you see the value `b`.

This is not a good practice and the compiler should issue a warning.
If you do not see the warning, try compiling with warnings enabled by using the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra` if using `gcc` or `clang`.

You can read more about this [here in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086600/warning-multi-character-character-constant-wmultichar).

Answer (score 1):

A character literal, for example `'A'`, has the type `int` with the value of `'A'`, most likely 0x41 (ASCII-Value for `A`).
When you have more than 1 byte in a character literal, for example `'ab'`, the result is implementation-defined. Note that the same applies to an Unicode codepoint when stored in UTF-8 with more than 1 byte, means every codepoint outside of ASCII, for example `'✓'` is a multi-character constant.

On my system it is still of type `int` and every byte is stored in 8 bit of this `int`, this is probably the case on your system as well. `'ab'` results in the value 0x6162, 0x61 is the value for `'a'` and 0x62 the value for `'b'`. You assign the value 0x6162 to a 8-bit `char`, you create UB when `char` is `signed`, so do not do that. In your case it stores the lower 8 bit of the value in the `char`, as it also would do when `unsigned char` is used. (Do not relay on this behavior in case of `signed char` or `char` on systems where `char` is signed).

You can test the value of `'ab'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned ch = 'ab';
  printf("0x%04X\n",ch);
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs `0x6162` on my system.